# R Search for a particular time from index

Tags: r, xts

I use an `xts` object. The index of the object is as below. There is one for every hour of the day for a year.

```
"2011-01-02 18:59:00 EST"
"2011-01-02 19:58:00 EST"
"2011-01-02 20:59:00 EST"
```

In columns are values associated with each index entry. What I want to do is calculate the standard deviation of the value for all Mondays at `18:59` for the complete year. There should be 52 values for the year.

I'm able to search for the day of the week using the `weekdays()` function, but my problem is searching for the time, such as `18:59:00` or any other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.index*` family of functions (don't forget the '.' in front of 'index'!):

```
fxts[.indexmon(fxts)==0]   # its zero-based (!) and gives you all the January values
fxts[.indexmday(fxts)==1]  # beginning of month
fxts[.indexwday(SPY)==1]   # Mondays

require(quantmod)

> fxts
                value
2011-01-02 19:58:00     1
2011-01-02 20:59:00     2
2011-01-03 18:59:00     3
2011-01-09 19:58:00     4
2011-01-09 20:59:00     5
2011-01-10 18:59:00     6
2011-01-16 18:59:00     7
2011-01-16 19:58:00     8
2011-01-16 20:59:00     9`

fxts[.indexwday(fxts)==1]  #this gives you all the Mondays
```

for subsetting the time you use

```
fxts["T19:30/T20:00"] # this will give you the time period you are looking for
```

and here you combine weekday and time period

```
fxts["T18:30/T20:00"] & fxts[.indexwday(fxts)==1] # to get a logical vector or
fxts["T18:30/T21:00"][.indexwday(fxts["T18:30/T21:00"])==1] # to get the values

>                   value
2011-01-03 18:58:00     3
2011-01-10 18:59:00     6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `interaction` to create a factor from the combination of `weekdays` and `.indexhour`, then use `split` to select the relevant observations from your xts object.

```
set.seed(21)
x <- .xts(rnorm(1e4), seq(1, by=60*60, length.out=1e4))
groups <- interaction(weekdays(index(x)), .indexhour(x))
output <- lapply(split(x, groups), function(x) c(count=length(x), sd=sd(x)))
output <- do.call(rbind, output)
head(output)
#            count        sd
# Friday.0      60 1.0301030
# Monday.0      59 0.9204670
# Saturday.0    60 0.9842125
# Sunday.0      60 0.9500347
# Thursday.0    60 0.9506620
# Tuesday.0     59 0.8972697
```